# WPF WebBrowser invoke a VBScript and retrieve its return value

Tags: wpf, browser

I have a WPF WebBrowser which loads a HTML page with vbScript functions on it from intranet
I want to execute one of these functions and retrieve the return value.

Unfortunately I have no ability to change the the intranet page

The function returns a boolean value and is as follows

```
Function IsAltered(strMode)

' This procedure checks to see if Changes have been made without saving.
Dim objItem, blnIsAltered
IsAltered = False
blnIsAltered = False

For Each objItem In window.document.all
    If (objItem.tagName = "INPUT" And objItem.className <> "Lbl" And objItem.className <> "NAF" And objItem.className <> "PreDispNoChange") Or _
       objItem.tagname = "SELECT" Or objItem.tagname = "TEXTAREA"  Then
        If Left(objItem.Id, 3) <> "hid" And objItem.Type <> "hidden" And objItem.Style.Visibility <> "hidden" Then
            If HasValueChanged(ObjItem.Id, Trim(objItem.Value)) Then
                blnIsAltered = True
                Exit For
            End if
        End If
    End If
Next
IsAltered = blnIsAltered   End Function
```

Can somebody suggest a way of implementing this

Thanks

Regards

Col

Answer (score 0):

System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser has a method called InvokeScript, which, according to the documentation "Executes a script function that is implemented by the currently loaded document."

You might want to try that.

Comment: I have tried using this but there are two issues 

1) I am getting the following error messsage 
   "Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))"

2) there is a return of void on invokeScript so I can't check if the function returns true or false?

Thanks
Colm

Comment: Apparently there are some issues with the WPF WebBrowser control.

See the StackOverflow issue regarding differences between the WPF and WinForms versions (see margin).

You may want to switch over to the WinForms version of WebBrowser. Don't forget that it is relatively easy to embed WinForms components in WPF. That way you get complete access to the HTML DOM.

Comment: After discussion with the team it has been decided to not replace the WPF webBrowser with Winforms one due to time constraints. I found a work around to this issue by using the IHTML class's to cehck if html page was altered from the wPF application logic. I'm curious if there is an update to the WPF web browser in the pipeline?

Comment: I guess that we will have to wait until this spring, when .NET 4/WPF 4 will be released...